# How to extract data from Promise returned in function call in array

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, base64, react-native-fs

I'm trying to convert nested array of images into base64 use RNFS and it is returning me a promise and response is in Promise,Can you help me how to just get string instead of Promise.Thanks
here is the ss
[image]

Here is my code

```
const items = order?.items?.map(i => {
        return {
          ...i,
          images: i.images.map(j => {
            let response = this.getBase64(j.path);
            return response;
          }),
        };
      });

 async getBase64(file) {
    return await RNFS.readFile(file, 'base64');
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the promise api to deal with your list of promises.

```
const promises = images.map(j => getBase64(j.path));
const imageResults = await Promise.all(promises); // wait for the promises to resolve.
// imageResults is now a list of whatever RNFS.readFile returns.
```

Comment: Thanks you made my day :)